# Open a detailViewController after use of UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, nsindexpath, uisearchbardelegate

I have a UISearchBar to search some data in a tableView and then, after searching, selecting a row to open a detailViewController . To do this it is necessary that the lines keep the index path and do not change the initial indexPath after the search, because otherwise I can not find the right elements in the database. How do I keep the initial indexPath? Are there any other methods?

```
 -(void) searchExpositorsTableView{
      [searchResult removeAllObjects]; 
      //In this array there are the elements resulted after research

      for (Database *currow in self.mutableArray){
         NSLog(@"list of expositors %@", self.mutableArray);

        NSRange titleResultsRange = [currow.name rangeOfString:self.searchBar.text options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];;
          if (titleResultsRange.length >0) {
                [searchResult addObject:currow.name];
                /*While I build this new array every indexPath change and the database
                  can not track down the original items*/
          }
        }

    NSLog(@"%@", searchResult);
   }

   -(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

      if(canSelectRow){

           NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);
           /*the indexPath is new and the database can not track down the original items*/
           return indexPath;

       }else{
        return nil;
       }
    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);
 }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   //Open wrong element
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if(searching) // where searching is boolean YES is searching, NO if not searched any element
    {
        //get your data from searchResults and open detailViewController
        Database *currow = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        DetailViewController = detailView = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
        [detailView release];
    }
    else
    {
        //get your data from self.mutableArray and open detailViewController
        Database *currow = [self.mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        DetailViewController = detailView = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
        [detailView release];
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I failed to create **SearchResult**. Instead of array of strings I did get array of elements of the database, this way I can extract elements.

Answer (score 1):

You may be passing searchResult Array in table view data methods to generate search research table view , in that case your table view indexpath.row and index of object in searchResult Array must be same : so use following

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  if(canSelectRow){
     NSString * name = [searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
/*
  or  you should instead save the Database object in searchResult Array directly instead of currow.name , in that case

       Database *currow = [searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;

    */

   }else{
    return nil;
   }
NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should use cell's tag for identification instead. Use this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 cell.tag = indexPath.row;
```

and then get indexpath back

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
        int ind = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].tag;
        //now you have real indexpath
    }
```